# How to test "Sign In with Apple" with test users?

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

Yes i am aware that this question has already been asked, but i don't seem to find any feasible solution.
How to test new apple signups with multiple accounts?

Comment: Do you mean using multiple Apple IDs in the same device?

Comment: @Raptor Yes, Like Facebook provides an option to create test users to check fb sign In.. In the same way does apple provide something like this?

Comment: At this moment, seems there is no similar mechanism. You have to create multiple normal Apple IDs to test.